# Fire event in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, raphael

I have an Raphael element with click event handler:

```
var paper = Raphael("container", 770, 160);
var c = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
c.click(function () {
    alert("triggering");
})
```

How I can manually fire this event? (`c.click()` don't work) 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `on` method? http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#eve.on

Comment: @Raminson Can you please give an example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although this question is already answered, I will post my solution which I found out by random.
It's possible with the Raphael internals:

When you attach an event listener like `element.click(func)` then the `element` object holds an array with all events. In this array there's an object which has a method `f` (strange naming convention) which triggers the event.

So to sum it up you can call your event with knowing the order of your events, in your case there's just the `click` event which is on index 0, you can call it like: `c.events[0].f();`

A more generic solution would be a function like

```
function triggerClick(element) {
    for(var i = 0, len = element.events.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (element.events[i].name == 'click') {
            element.events[i].f();
        }
    }
}​
```

But beware that if you had multiple `click` events all were triggered.

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FHKvu/) to demonstrate.

Comment: This works great for me. Wish Raphael would open up some way to do it without hacks tho

Answer (score 3):

Even though this has already been answered a while ago, I was looking for something a little "more native" in nature.  Here's how I go about it without relying on Mootools or jQuery.

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
evObj.initEvent('click', true, false); 
c.node.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

This basically creates the event in the browser and then dispatches it to the node associated with the Raphaël object.

Here's also the MOZ link for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :

The solution purposed by Dan Lee is working better.

Comment: Sorry I think it is better ^^

Comment: No problem I think there is a better way using raphael. I'm searching if found it I will post it.

Comment: @ArturKeyan But if you actually click on it, the event is not fired! See my answer for the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a slightly more elegant way to use Kris' method.
Raphael supports native extension of the element object so I built a little patch to add the trigger method to raphael

here it is:

```
//raphael programatic event firing
    Raphael.el.trigger = function (str, scope, params){ //takes the name of the event to fire and the scope to fire it with
        scope = scope || this;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++){
            if(this.events[i].name === str){
                this.events[i].f.call(scope, params);
            }
        }
    };
```

I set up a Js fiddle to show how it works: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJWsW/)

Answer (score 0):

I write a plug-in for this, use event to calculate the right position;

```
Raphael.el.trigger = function(evtName, event) {
    var el = this[0];      //get pure elements;
    if (event.initMouseEvent) {     // all browsers except IE before version 9
        var mousedownEvent = document.createEvent ("MouseEvent");
        mousedownEvent.initMouseEvent (
            "mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 
            event.screenX, event.screenY, event.clientX, event.clientY, 
            event.ctrlKey, event.altKey, event.shiftKey, event.metaKey, 
            0, null);
        el.dispatchEvent (mousedownEvent);
    } else {
        if (document.createEventObject) {   // IE before version 9
            var mousedownEvent = document.createEventObject (window.event);
            mousedownEvent.button = 1;  // left button is down
            el.fireEvent (evtName, mousedownEvent);
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
circle2.mousedown(function(e) {
  var circle = this.clone();
  circle.drag(move, down, up);
  circle.trigger("mousedown", e);
});
```